# Possible to move Windows 8 to 10 upgrade installation out of virtual machine?

Tags: windows-10

I have a VM in which I installed Windows 8. Later I used the free upgrade to upgrade the VM to Windows 10.

Now I wish to move Windows 10 out of the VM to run directly on the system hardware. My question is, is this possible with the free upgrade? Or is the upgrade license tied to the VM now?

Comment: The answer to your question depends if your Windows 8 license was OEM or Retail

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot move it. The free Windows 10 upgrades are tied to a generated system ID, which is based from the motherboard and MAC address I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you may need to call Microsoft to get it activated.

You can either call Microsoft upon installation, or use an external program  such as [Produkey](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html) to retrieve the key for installation

(Note that retrieving the key may still require you to call Microsoft, but it may also allow you to simply activate over the internet)